# Switching between button class's using localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to use javascript to switch between class's when I push a button. At the same time keeping their state the same when the page is refreshed. The script below runs correctly, because I see the button changes state when clicked. However, when the page is refreshed it is all gone. I did read around this forum about using a cookie in jquery, but I thought I would use local storage because why not.  
What am I doing wrong please?

```
<button name='idButton'  class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open' id=confirmButton onclick='addBasket(this)'>Click Me</button>

<script>
     function addBasket($element) {
    var className = $element.getAttribute("class");
    if (className == "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open") {
        $element.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close";
    }
    else {
        $element.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open";
    }

    localStorage.setItem("item",  $element); //Store the element so it can be accessed later.
     localStorage.setItem("class", $element.className); //Store the last class name
}
localStorage.getItem("item").className = localStorage.getItem("class").name;
//The last line should run when page loads because it is outside the scope of the method  
</script>
```

Comment: you can't store elements in localStorage unless you stringify them as objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store an element in localStorage. It only stores strings.

Try the following:

```
//Storing
localStorage.setItem("class", className);

//Page Load (after element exists)
var btnClass = localStorage.getItem("class")
if (btnClass) {
  document.getElementById('confirmButton ').className = btnClass;
}
```

for more advanced objects you can JSON.stringify to store and JSON.parse when you retrieve from storage

Comment: Thank you. As soon as you said it can only store strings, I knew what I was doing wrong. It works now. Sorry for the stupidity

Comment: No worries. That's what this site is all about.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I made an example for persistent button states using dynamically created buttons. You can check out the comments to see what is going on! [Persistent Button State using LocalStorage](https://codepen.io/marcusparsons/pen/GyVdPZ?editors=0110)

```
//These are shortcut helper methods
let select = document.querySelector.bind(document);
let selectAll = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);


function init() {
  //First, create grid of buttons (for testing)
  let sethtml = '';
  for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
      sethtml += "<button class='glyphicon changestate glyphicon-eye-open' id='eyebtn" + x + "" + y + "' onclick='changeState(this)'></button>";
    }
    sethtml += '<br>';
  }
  document.body.innerHTML = sethtml;

  //Next, get all of the elements whose state can be changed and are persistent
  let changeEls = selectAll('.changestate');
  //for each one in this list
  for (var i = 0; i < changeEls.length; i++) {
    let el = changeEls[i];
    let id = el.id;
    //see if there is a reference to them already in the storage
    //and if there is not add that reference
    if (localStorage) {
      if (!localStorage.getItem(id)) {
        //Save the states of the buttons to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify([id, JSON.stringify(el.classList)]));
      }
      else {
        //Set the states based on stored data
        let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(id));
        let elid = data[0];
        let classList = JSON.parse(data[1]);
        //Eliminate previous classes
        document.getElementById(elid).className = "";
        //Add in classes gathered from storage
        for (let myclass in classList) {
          select('#' + elid).classList.add(classList[myclass]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//Change state of each button
function changeState(el) {
  let id = el.id;
  //if open, set to close
  if (el.classList.contains('glyphicon-eye-open')) {
    el.classList.remove('glyphicon-eye-open');
    el.classList.add('glyphicon-eye-close');
  }
  //if close, set to open
  else {
    el.classList.remove('glyphicon-eye-close');
    el.classList.add('glyphicon-eye-open');
  }
  if (localStorage) {
    //set the localStorage to reflect this
    localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify([id, JSON.stringify(el.classList)]));
  }
}

init();
```

Comment: Will this stop overriding? Because this is my problem now. If I click another button the local storage is overridden. Thanks for the post too

Comment: This saves the class state of everything to unique localStorage containers that are based on the id of each element.  So, as long as you name your elements with unique ids each time (which you should be doing), each element has its own unique classList.

Comment: Be sure to click on the link I posted where you can test out the codepen, fork it, and modify it.